# Can I get certificates for other recipients of an encrypted email?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, public-key-encryption

I run into this problem fairly often at work using Outlook. There is an email thread going and someone decides to encrypt their response to the group (sometimes justified, sometimes not). Now I want to Reply-All to continue the conversation, but I don't have the certificates for half of the recipients.

Is there a way to get the public certificates for all recipients on an encrypted email, or is that just an impossibility? Clearly the sender would have needed them all to encrypt the first email, but I don't know if those public certificates are included and visible to all other recipients as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message does not carry the recipients' actual certificates – it includes only enough information to allow them to identify themselves as recipients, but most likely not enough information for you or someone else to download them.

For example, in S/MIME, the 'RecipientInfo' field only includes the certificate's issuer + serial number, *or* the certificate's "subject key identifier" (public key hash), but not the actual public key, let alone the actual certificate. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35222353/49849) and [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5652#section-6.2).)

(In the idealized OSI world, issuer + serial number would be sufficient to retrieve the certificate from "The Directory" via X.500 or LDAP, in reality not so much. Although if the recipients are within the same Active Directory system their certificates *could* be stored in their AD user account objects.)

Likewise, in OpenPGP, the 'Public-Key Encrypted Session Key' packet only includes a 64-bit key ID of the specific *encryption subkey* that's necessary to decrypt the message – not even the full fingerprint.

The key ID can be searched on various public keyservers, although it's too short to be used for serious verification (by now it is possible to generate keys with chosen 64-bit key IDs).

Comment: 32-bit 'short' keyids, which many programs including gnupg used to use on the UI for convenience, can [practically be faked](https://evil32.com/) for a few years now, but not 64-bit 'long' keyids. Otherwise concur; not many people today recall why X.509 is numbered 'under' X.500.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: While 64 bits is still hard, it's approximately the difficulty level of BTC mining now, isn't it? (The fingerprint is a SHA1 hash.)

Comment: Bitcoin is now about 2^65 SHA256d per second, but: (1) PGP key generation is hundreds to many thousands of times more costly than hashing and (2) more important Bitcoin mining is now done entirely with ASICs which are billions of times faster but cost $billions to develop, funded by a large number of people willing to spend lots of money for a legal competitive advantage. I don't believe there are lots of rich people who want to attack PGP, and even if there are I don't think they can pool their funds for that purpose without risking arrest.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: Right, but (1) you don't need to generate two keypairs, just one (subkeys aren't included in main fingerprint), and you don't need the complex RSA key generation process either, as you can target Ed25519 where any 253-bit string is a valid key. (2) you don't need to do it in 10 minutes, depending on your target and goals you can keep your cluster cracking at the same key-ID for months. Which, yes, in practice it's probably quite unlikely for someone to do this... and yet, doesn't seem at all unrealistic.

Comment: Agree about subkeys, which I didn't mention, but even for DSA/ElG, EC, Ed/X keypairs you must compute the public key (number or point or coordinate) which is much costlier than hashing. If you have a thousand computers and each can do a thousand trials per second, it'll take nearly a million years. Even with a million computers it's about a thousand years. I for one don't expect to live that long.

Answer (score 2):

To send encrypted to one or more recipients, you must have the
public key of each recipient stored in his contact information.

You may save in Outlook the public key of any of your contacts
this way:

- Request that the contact send you a signed e-mail.
  An indicator will appear on the e-mail to indicate it is signed.
- Right-click on the sender's name and click "Add to Outlook Contacts"
  (even if he is already a contact)
- Enter the details of the new contact and click Save.
  If they are an existing contact, choose "Yes" to update the
  contact details.

Note: When you add or update a contact directly from
a signed e-mail, Outlook will pull in the sender's public key
and associate it with the contact details.
Now when you send an encrypted e-mail, it will know
what certificate to use for the recipient.

Comment: wasn't the OP's question on how to get the public keys not on how to store them, or did I missunderstood s.th. here??

Comment: @Albin: Getting is done from any encrypted message, but it needs to be saved to use.

Comment: ok, I didn't see your the "request", thanks...  so the signer would attach his public key to the signed message or where does outlook "pull the key" from? A little off topic: doesn't that allow e.g. for a man in the middle attack? As far as I know the public key should be sent through a secure channel?! Or is there some other kind of build in verification to check the authentication?

Comment: @Albin: The public key is ... public, so there is no security involved (and no secure channel without it). The attachment is done automatically by Outlook.

Comment: Agree with harrymc, only the recipient who has the private key that matches the public key used to encrypt the message can decipher the message for reading.

Comment: @harrymc: It doesn't need to be secret, sure, but it does need to be *authenticated* somehow – to avoid being tricked into encrypting to the wrong key.

Comment: @Christy thanks for you feedback, although I must say, I disagree (unless I missunderstood you). if a public key that is attached to the email is used for descryption it's senseless. A man in the middle attack would just catch the email, change it, encrypt it with a different private key and just attach the "new" corresponding public key to the email. A decryption with the attached key, would still show a valid signature. There is virtual no security unless the public key is transferred via a secure channel the can verify the authentication of the sender.

Comment: @harrymc not quite, see my explanation to Christy why "secure" transfer is still necessary, even for the public key. I made an example on how an attack would be possible without the secure transfer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the owner of the public/private key pair, everyone can choose for themselves on how to distribute the public key (see [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/406/how-should-i-distribute-my-public-key)). There is no general answer here.

Worst case the public keys have not been publicly published, then you'll have to ask the sender for his/her public key. I used to attach my public key in my messages - which is sort of (very) unsecure since it leaves quite a bit of room for different attack types. Therefore I don't think this option is used as an automatic key exchange, but I'm not 100% sure.

I assume Outlook just sends an encrypted message to people it knows the public key and to everyone else it sends an unencrypted message (you can probable tell Outlook what to do via some kind of setting). But I'm guessing here, I never used this Outlook feature.

Note: if it's a work environment, the public keys are probable handled by a server, and integrated into the exchange server thus integrated in Outlook, you might want to ask your IT department. Or just ask a person who did send out the encrypted email on how they did it.

Note2: Assuming the mail you are getting actually is a multi-key encrypted mail (some background info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953707/smime-decryption-for-multiple-recipients) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597188/encryption-decryption-with-multiple-keys)) - which wasn't 100% clear without the comments (could have been a shared private key as well)

This answer was edited according to the new info from the comments.

Comment: I assume the whole group can decrypt the message, but we definitely don't all share the same private key. I'm pretty sure it's being encrypted for each individual based on their own public key. Is that not how Outlook encrypts emails sent to multiple people?

Comment: @DavidK if it's a public/private key encryption and the whole group can decrypt the *same* encrypted message, they *must* share the same private key. Otherwise something else is going on... e.g. that everyone actually gets a different message (with his/her public key encryption). Most likely a setting in your exchange environment, more info is needed here.

Comment: I'm talking about Microsoft Outlook encrypting based on people's certificates. Whenever I try to send an encrypted email, if I don't have the certificate saved for any of the contacts then I get a pop-up warning me that I can either send unencrypted, or send encrypted and recipients A, B, and C won't be able to read it.

Comment: @DavidK as I said, there is no "universal" place where people save their public key unless it's set up by a "group administrator" of some kind (usually the IT department). I would just ask the person who sent the encrypted email, this will be the easiest way (or ask your IT department).

Comment: Also, not all of the recipients are on the same exchange server or even at the same company. This type of encryption is very common in my industry and is used across thousands of different organizations. This is why I'm having a hard time understanding why the answer is just "ask your IT".

Comment: @Albin: Both PGP and S/MIME support multi-recipient encryption, where the message carries multiple copies of same symmetric "session key" that are individually encrypted to each recipient's public key. (For example, this is [how it looks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35222353/49849) inside a S/MIME message.)

Comment: @user1686 thanks for the info/link (that how I guessed it might work, never used it myself though) I updated my answer. Still the problem remains that there is no "universal" place where everyone store his/her public key (especially with independent organizations and individuals). I suppose, Outlook just send the encrypted email to recipients who's public keys it knows and to everyone else unencrypted... but I don't know Outlook/Exchange that well, I'm just guessing here....